# Why is LINQ treating its index as a string?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, closures

LINQ appears to be adding its index (using the 2-parameter overload to `.Select`; I assume LINQ generates the index since dictionaries have none) to an integer using string concatenation rather than addition.

The following code returns `myStr_3`, `myStr_13`, `myStr_23`, i.e. it is adding the dictionary index `i` and the integer `count` as if they were strings, so `1 + 3` becomes `13` rather than `4`:

```
// myDictionary is <string, object>
int parmCount = parameters.Count; // 3
int count = parmCount; // Closure safety
var setValues = myDictionary.Select((d, i) => "myStr_" + i + count);
```

Apparently index 0 is equivalent to an empty string rather than "0". Weird.

The following code (note the extra parens) returns correct results; `myStr_3`, `myStr_4`, `myStr_5`:

```
int parmCount = parameters.Count; // 3
int count = parmCount;
var setValues = myDictionary.Select((d, i) => "myStr_" + (i + count));
```

Update: Since `"myStr_" + i` produced "correct results", I jumped to the conclusion that the use of an additional integer variable was being handled improperly without really thinking about how `i` was being used. LINQ's behavior is, of course, completely correct. I just need to stop posting questions when I am tired.

MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The second argument to selector represents the zero-based index of
>   that element in the source sequence.

While the index type isn't spelled out, this to me, and the word "index", implies a numeric type.

Why is LINQ adding two integers as if they were strings?

Comment: can you post a reproducable example? [I can't reproduce it at the moment](https://dotnetfiddle.net/j6vjpG)

Comment: Your first code should produce output like `myStr_03` and not `myStr_3`

Comment: @Habib You are correct. See response to Selman22 below.
This question has not been my finest on SO. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is LINQ adding two integers as if they were strings?

It not LINQ, but string concatenation, If you have a `string + int + int` without any `()`, all will be treated as `string` as `ToString` method will be called for each operands.

This:

```
"myStr_" + i + count
```

Turns to something like:

```
string.Concat("myStr_",i,count);
```

which internally calls, `ToString` on each parameter.

But when you have code like:

```
"myStr_" + (i + count)
```

Then because of parenthesis having higher [precedence that `+` operator.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx) integer arithmetic is performed for `i` and `count` and then their result is concatenated in the string.

As a side note, `Dictionary` is not an ordered collection, so you can't be sure to get same order every time.

See: [Dictionary C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as
>   a KeyValuePair structure representing a value and its
>   key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

EDIT: for your comment:

> I had considered this, but: .Select((d, i) => "myStr_" + i); (no free
>   variable count) does addition, not string concatenation.

It is still string concatenation. You are seeing the changed value of `i` due to `Select`. On each enumeration, value of `i` is the index of element, so you get something like:

```
"myStr_" + 0
"myStr_" + 1
"myStr_" + 2
"myStr_" + 3
.....
```

Again, this value of `i` could change for the same element, as dictionaries are not ordered collection.

See [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx) overload which provides an index.

> The second argument to selector represents the zero-based index of
>   that element in the source sequence. This can be **useful if the
>   elements are in a known order** and you want to do something with an
>   element at a particular index,

Comment: @CharlesBurns, that still does string concatenation, but it is just that in each enumeration value of `i` is incremented due to `Select`

Comment: it is worth noting that `"myStr_" + (i + count)` evaluates `i + count` first because parentheses have higher precedence than `+`

Comment: I had considered this, but got all confused when use of JUST the index produced what I considered correct results. Now that I think about it, I was just not carefully considering what was going on when just using the index. Silly mistake.

Comment: I still don't get it how it returns `myStr_3`... was that a typo in the question? it certainly should not ignore the index 0.

Comment: @Selman22, it doesn't. There is something else that could be wrong in the question.

Comment: @Selman22 Good question. That also threw me off. The answer appears to be that something happened between getting the string from the VS debugger and putting it in the post. That something must be me, because the preceding zero is there when I run the code now.